# How to display debug message rather than error message?

Tags: excel, vba, vbe

My VBA editor used to show a debug message when an error occurred.

[image]

When I use VBA on another computer it only pops up an error message.

[image]

How can I set the debug message box to appear again?

Comment: You need to include the code generating the original error.

Comment: @Robin Mackenzie any code error in my other computer show only alert message instead of debug message box. I will provide an example tomorrow when i test in my other computer.

Comment: Is the code project locked?

Comment: Doing a web search leads to a suggestion of changing your settings to Break In Class Modules. This would seem to apply if the error is in a Workbook, Worksheet, UserForm or other class module.

Comment: On your own machine you probably have VBA error handling (Tools > Options > General) set to "break on all errors" - in that case even "handled" errors will give you the Debug dialog.  Your other machine probably does not have that option set.